# Niceness and System showing high CPU in top

Tags: linux, kernel, performance, top

We use a VM/server as the jump box to our other servers, it holds all the RSA keys. I keep getting alerts that the CPU is over 75% from VMware. We run 3 bash scripts on there - just general checking to the DB's and perforce. I had noticed when I looked into top, it had a high niceness CPU and system CPU.

[image]

I was just wondering, is there any way I can bring them down and hopefully bring down the overall CPU so I don't get the alarms from VMware? I'm not too sure on what to look into on how to do this.

Comment: Is the issue the warnings from VMware or that the system is actually utilized at above 75%?

Comment: Looks like some of those shell scripts are doing `while true; do thing_that_does_something _short; done`. If you add a `sleep` in the loop, it will use less CPU.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. @Kusalananda - I believe the system is above 75%.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick - I'm new to bash scripting, where would I add the sleep command?

Comment: If the ping-to-db.sh script is short and you can remove any sensitive information from it, you can add it to your question and we can offer suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If, as Mark Plotnick suggests, the shell scripts are doing something in a tight loop, such as

```
while true; do
    command_to_do_something
done
```

(or something equivalent) then this may cause the script to use a lot of system resources in terms of CPU.

The loop can be slowed down by simply inserting a `sleep` call:

```
while true; do
    command_to_do_something
    sleep 60
done
```

This would introduce a 60 second pause during which the script will do absolutely nothing, hence freeing up resources.